# Como usar RegisterStartupScript um seguido do outro?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

É possível usar `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` um seguido do outro?

Pois preciso usar um como `tabChange();` e outro para exibir o modal, mas no caso ele só executa o primeiro.

Código:

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "OK", "tabChange();tabChange();", True)

    Dim gBll As New Geral_BLL
    gBll.atribuiMensagemModal(Me.Master, dcResultado)
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "OK", "openModal()", True)
    gBll = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

veja se assim já não resolve.

```
 Dim gBll As New Geral_BLL           
 gBll.atribuiMensagemModal(Me.Master, dcResultado)            
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "OK", "tabChange();tabChange();openModal()", True)
gBll = Nothing
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu sim!